# how to display polygon on google map from extracted coordinates from web services in android studio

Tags: android

I have extracted polygon coordinates from web service as follow:

```
[{\"type\":\"POLYGON\",\"id\":4,\"geometry\":

[[[18.453445111946866,73.80514847613517],[18.453445111946866,73.80860316134635],

[18.451999947470625,73.8083242116088],[18.451999947470625,73.80499827243034]]]}]"
```

Now i have to display it on a map. How can I display it? in android studio

Answer (score 1):

```
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = list.get(z);
        options.add(point);
    }
    line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

You can try this for drawing a polyline from multiple latlng. Only create latlng of each lat & lng you are getting from server.